# Xmonad Win-L conflicts with Windows desktop

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xmonad

So I have **xmonad** running remotely. All is good and I'm using the <kbd>Win</kbd> key instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd>. The problem is, when I want to resize an xmonad window with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, this locks the screen in my **Windows** desktop. How can I rebind <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to something like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the source code for the default mappings [here](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad/src/XMonad-Config.html). To rebind the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> key to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> you can use the `additionalKeys` function to add new key bindings to your config:

```
import XMonad.Util.EZConfig

main = xmonad $ defaultConfig {
         ...
     } `additionalKeys` [
        ((shiftMask .|. mod1Mask, xK_h), sendMessage Expand)
     ]
```

Comment: emacs tells me `additionalKeys` is not in scope. Sorry, I don't speak Haskell yet. How can I correct this?

Comment: Ah, sorry, you need to import the `XMonad.Util.EZConfig` module to get access to that function.

Comment: couldn't match type XConfig l0 -> KeyMask ... probable cause: modMask is applied to too few arguments

Comment: Updated the snippet, it should be mod1Mask for the alt key.

Comment: Awesome. I changed it to **mod4Mask** to make it **`Win`+`Shift`+`H`**. Thanks!